# How to repair a flat RJ45 cable and connector?

Tags: cable, repair, connector, rj-45

My son installed a flat RJ45 cable with moulded connectors between two rooms in our house. However, the connector and cable at one end got torn off. Pulling a new cable is sadly not an option, so - thinking back to the old days - I thought I would buy a crimper and some connectors and try to repair it myself. Given the hourly rates of electricians here in Switzerland, the crimper would easily be amortised within 30 minutes :-(

I went to Pusterla in Zurich, which is the go-to shop for anything real and electronic, but they were not aware of appropriate crimpers and/or connectors ("the cables are moulded in factories"). So I conclude that either it's impossible or the technology hasn't reached Zurich yet...

Looking at the torn-off connector, it seems to me that any RJ45 crimper would do. Is this correct?

That being the case, the problem is presumably the connector. What term should I use to ensure that I find the right type of connector when searching on the net? Or is it really impossible?

Back in the day I used to make my own RJ11 cables: is there any fundamental difference (other than size and the number of wires) with RJ45?

Steve

[image: This is what the torn-off end of the cable looks like]

Answer (score 0):

I just googled "rj45 crimpzange" and got [RJ45 Crimp Zange](https://www.brack.ch/velleman-crimpzange-rj45-113565). The problem might be to get RJ45 connector in small numbers, if 20 pieces are too many for you. Although, 20 pieces for below CHF20 is probably still an option for you.

I'm baffled that Pusterla didn't know about that, despite having one.

Comment: Thanks. Finding a crimper is not the issue, though: it’s getting the right one for a flat cable and its connector.

Comment: Apropos Pusterla: they couldn’t do the crimper and connector combination. So I appreciate them not taking money off me for a crimper that might not work for my (flat) cable.

Answer (score 0):

You can get crimpable 8P8C modular connectors ("RJ45") and pliers in pretty much any decent electronics shop. If your local shop doesn't have them try online.

Note that generic connectors are made for stranded (flexible) cables, AWG26 or so. Cables with solid conductors/wires require special connectors, as do very thin, stranded cables. Flat cables are usually AWG32 or so and may not provide good contact with a generic connector.

While you're at it you might want to get a simple cable tester as well (10€ or so). While those things cannot *really* test a network cable's quality, they're totally OK to check correct pairing and continuity which might be an issue with crimping thin cable.

Ich drück die Daumen. ;-)

Comment: Hi @Zac67, we meet again :-)  My cable is about 5mm x 1.5mm, so I guess it’s AWG32. That helps already in my search. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, looks like it.

Comment: I recently put normal connectors on cables you normally put into walls, I don’t know the correct name. It was very easy and made no problem at all, the connection speed is top

Comment: Given the AWG32 hint, my son found this: https://youtu.be/CEPMQ4wybgI which contains a reference to a flat RJ45 connector. The flat RJ45 connector strikes me as being what I am looking for. Together with a standard crimper. And tester :-)

Comment: That flat cable looks like it not twisted at all - that's a plain modular but no network cable. Your flat Cat-6 cable has twisted pairs that need to be sorted into the connector in the TIA-568A or -B scheme (see other end) with pairs in 1-2, 3-6, 4-5, 7-8

Comment: I've added a photo of the torn-off end of the cable to my original question. If you look at it closely the wires don't look twisted either. If you flatten a twisted pair to try and feed it into a connector, it doesn't look twisted any more. I've found another source (https://www.vpi.us/dpdf/200/assemble-cat5e-6-usf.pdf) for a connector which is explicitly AWG32 and RJ45 too: the images also appear untwisted.

Comment: The pairs are twisted, just at a low rate, otherwise they wouldn't work. Just make sure you crimp them in the right order - check the intact side when in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

It is of cause possible to crimp your own network cables, you only need the correct tools. You need some kind of cutter to open the cable shield, and pliers in addition to the crumpet, but you can also buy a two-in-one tool instead of the crimper that fulfills the need of the pliers as well. Then you can just install new connectors.

---

Natürlich ist es möglich, einfach einen neuen Stecker aufzucrimpen. Ich habe das in den letzten Wochen für unser neues Heimnetzwerk öfters gemacht, es geht relativ einfach, wenn man sich dran gewöhnt hat. Einfach entweder ein Crimp-Werkzeug oder eine Kombi-Netzwerk-Zange kaufen, dazu Stecker zum Crimpen, die Kosten je nach Abschrimung zwischen 1 und 3 Euro, abhängig davon, wo man schaut.
Ich habe jetzt zwar keine Erfahrung mit Flachkabeln, aber das müsste eigentlich auch gut gehen.

Comment: Thanks. See the discussion with Zac67, which goes into the niceties of flat cable. Ordinary round cable would be a no-brainer, as you seem to suggest.

Comment: As there are obviously the same number of wires in the cable, and just the overall cable is different, it should be possible to just use a normal connector, but if you have the correct ones it is certain better

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to round of this discussion with the report that I managed successfully to fix the cable.

I used the following:

- plug: RJ45-PLG-USF
- crimper: CRIMP-RJ45-SF

I ordered them from VPI in Aurora, OH, USA. They took a little over two weeks to reach here (Switzerland). The USPS tracking system stopped giving any updates once they had left Chicago (about 6 days after VPI shipped them), so it was a pleasant surprise when they eventually appeared in my letter box. I chose VPI because their online documentation was sufficiently explicit for me to be sure I would get what I wanted. The equipment was actually made in Taiwan.

The crimper needed to be adjusted for SF plugs, but that was well documented and easy to do. Preparing the cable and fitting it into the plug was fairly straightforward, though I would recommend using a pair of very fine tweezers, particularly if you have large fingers. You just have to make sure the colours of the cable in the new plug are in the same order as at the other end of the cable (or the old plug, of course). My colours didn't match any scheme in the accompanying documentation for some reason.

The biggest problem I had was when our cat decided he was going to help me. Sadly, his feline skills were not up to it.

My thanks to those who provided advice: that helped me to work out exactly what I needed to order.

Steve